# Can't send mails to .de mail, heelp?

Tags: email, cpanel

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; lvpmailfs1.vip.hr
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 4545360041
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; shops@ibci.hr
Arrival-Date: Mon, 20 Apr 2015 12:35:14 +0200 (CEST)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; kk@cutic.de
Original-Recipient: rfc822;kk@cutic.de
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mx01.schlund.de
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable 550
    invalid DNS MX or A/AAAA resource record
```

I'm getting this bounce email only when sending to `.de` domains, can anyone point me on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this issues only from your account ? Please try to send test mail from free mail provider.(Gmail, Hotmail). I think recipient e-mail domain is not setup correctly and that is the reason you are getting this issues.